# R-gsub is working correctly within a function

Tags: r

I have a function that looks like this

```
Common_errors=function(data,pattern,column){
    Type1=all(unlist(strsplit(pattern, "")) == 'C')
    Type2=all(unlist(strsplit(pattern, "")) == 'N')

    if( Type1==TRUE){data[,column]=gsub(0, "o", data[,column])}
    if( Type2==TRUE){data[,column]=gsub("o", 0, data[,column])}
    data}
```

The function checks whether a column should contain all letters or numbers. If it should contain all numbers then any o founds are changed to 0. If it should contain all letters any 0 found are changed to o. The code is working fine outside the function. But within the function no change is been made to the original data set. Any help greatly appreciated.

The data set I am working with is just something I made up quickly to test the code and looks like

```
   Client Country
1      10      Po
2      20      Po
3      30      Po
4      40      Po
5      50      Po
6      60      Po
7      70      Po
8      8o      Po
9      90      P0
10    100      Po
11    11o      Po
12    120      Po
13    130      US
14    140      US
15    150      US
16    160      FS
17    170      US
18    180      US
19    190      US
```

This is the output of

```
dput(head(df,10))

structure(list(correct = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), V = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("FS", "P0", "Po", "US"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I mean which values you provide to Common_errors(data=X,pattern=X,column=X). However, `Common_errors(data=df,pattern='C',column='Country')` and `Common_errors(data=df,pattern='N',column='Client')` work for me

Comment: @A.Suliman it does print the correct values. However I am having difficult storing that data set to use.

Comment: `data <- Common_errors(data,pattern,column)`?